# How do I pass hyperlinks into Carrot Search FoamTree?

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-visualization

I am using Carrot Search FoamTree code to add hyperlinks to my html page. Here is my code:

```
<script>
  // Initialize FoamTree after the whole page loads to make sure
  // the element has been laid out and has non-zero dimensions.
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var foamtree = new CarrotSearchFoamTree({
      // Identifier of the HTML element defined above
      id: "visualization",

      // Some data to visualize.
      dataObject: { groups: [
          { label: "Alkaloid", weight: 1.0, trigger: true},
          { label: "Flavonoids", weight: 3.0 },
          { label: "Terpenoids", weight: 2.0 },
          { label: "Alkaloid", weight: 1.0 },
          { label: "Flavonoids", weight: 3.0 },
          { label: "Terpenoids", weight: 2.0 },
          { label: "Steroids", weight: 4.0 }
        ]},

    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to produce hyperlinks for Alkaloids, Flavonoids, Terpenoids and Steroids. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem by passing extra parameters into the dataObject, especially useful when a foamtree drills down into another foamtree.  I do the same with circles, for example passing parentId and parentName into sub objects so when the `onclick event` fires you have all the info you need in the event object as it just passes you that object, which contains your `group`, so passing a `url` to be used in an even could simply be placed into the `group` object.